# prove that $ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge 2\left( {a^3 b^3 + a^3 c^3 + c^3 b^3 + 4a^2 b^2 c^2 } \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have:

> let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative real numbers with sum $2$. Prove that 
>   $$a^2  + b^2  + c^2  \ge 2\left( {a^3 b^3  + a^3 c^3  + c^3 b^3  + 4a^2 b^2 c^2 } \right)$$

I should determine whether this is a convergent or divergent integral. The problem is that I don't know how to start.

Comment: There is no integral anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This inequality is come from?  This inequality can use this

$$\Longleftrightarrow \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)^4}{16}-2(\sum{a^3b^3}+4a^2b^2c^2)=\frac{3abc(a+b+c)}{4}\sum{(a-b)^2}+\sum\frac{c(2a+2b+c)(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}{16}+\frac{(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2}{2}+\frac{a^2b^2c^2}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Since $\sum\limits_{cyc}a^3b^3=27v^6-27uv^2w^3+3w^6$, we see that our inequality is equivalent to $f(w^3)\geq0$,

where $f$ is a concave function, which says that it's enough to prove our inequality

for an extremal value of $w^3$, which happence in the following cases.

1. $w^3=0$.

Let $c=0$. Thus, we need to prove that $$a^2+b^2\geq2a^3b^3,$$
which is AM-GM: $a^2+b^2\geq2ab$ and it's enough to prove that $ab\leq1$,
which follows from our condition: $2=a+b\geq2\sqrt{ab}$;

2. $b=a$ and $c=2-2a$, where $0\leq a\leq1$.

In this case we need to prove that
$$2a^2+4(1-a)^2\geq2(a^6+2a^3(2-2a)^3+4a^4(2-2a)^2)$$ or
$$(1-a)(a^5+17a^4-15a^3+a^2-2a+2)\geq0,$$
which is true.

Done!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the KKT condition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush-Kuhn-Tucker_conditions

As a hint, here's a physicist's argument: given the symmetry among the 3 variables, the optimal value is likely to occur at the high-symmetry scenario when a=b=c. And you'll see that the inequality holds.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "likely"?

Comment: The exact meaning is that, if the problem satisfies certain conditions, you will find the optimal solution of the following optimization problem, maximizing (LHS - RHS) subject to a+b+c=2, to be a=b=c.

Comment: Don't you mean minimizing (LHS-RHS)?

Comment: Ok, what are those conditions? The problem "Maximize $a^3+b^3+c^3$ subject to $a^2+b^2+c^2 = 1$" doesn't satisfy those conditions, so symmetry isn't enough.

Comment: @PhilipHoskins Yes.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 You are correct that symmetry isn't enough. One can derive the conditions using the KKT. In any case, researchers would exploit all the symmetries to understand and/or simplify their problems.

Comment: Can anyone kindly explain the downvotes to me? I'm new to this website, and I was trying to help. The KKT condition is the canonical answer to this type of problem, and I provide an elegant and effective way of thinking about this problem. It would be great if someone explains to me why my answer deserves the downvotes.

Comment: The minimum here, if true, happens at a non-symmetric settings: $(a,b,c)=(1,1,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution has less symmetry than the case of a=b=c but has more symmetry than an arbitrary solution.

Comment: "One can derive the conditions using the KKT" Glad to know, then please show precisely how this applies to the present case. Otherwise, the assertion that "You can use the KKT condition" might appear as an uninformed sleight of hand.